# mod rewrite rule for a url with multiple get variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im new to url rewriting, Im able to build simple rules but unable to build a rule for a url consisting of multiple get variables

**My url is:**
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters

**I want a clean url like:**
http://www.mywebsite.com/voters

Kindly help me in building the correct rewrite rule for the above 'clean url'

Comment: We noticed uid is changing if different users are logging in and similarly other variables can changing in certain circumstances? What will be rewrite rule if the variables (AKey, uid, cl, req) are dynamic in this url [ http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^voters/?$ /index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters [L,QSA,NC]
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cl=$1&req=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! It worked with slight modification, have remove the '/' preceding index.php, corrected rewrite rule is ..                       RewriteRule ^voters/?$ index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: We noticed uid is changing if different users are logging in and similarly other variables can change in certain circumstances? What will be rewrite rule if the variables (AKey, uid, cl, req) are dynamic in this url [ http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters]

Comment: `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?AKey=fjdsakfd&uid=2&cl=Election&req=Voters]` is the actual URL to load content but what URL do you want in browser to show for this?

Comment: We want a clean url, expected url is "mywebsite.com/2/Election/Voters"   ignore AKey value .. we will make coding changes to make it a static value.