# url rewrite rule for a single page application

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a single page application that is based on a index.php that loads all the css and js needed. Then in a div inside the page I load all the application functionalities using jQuery `.load()`. Each time I load something via the menu with this function I also do:

```
window.history.pushState({},null,url);
```

to write an entry in the browser history that will look like:

```
https://example.org/creditmanager/index.php?area=masterdata&sub=pf
```

every page will have an unique match of area and sub. Everything works fine besides back and forth buttons in the navigation bar. If I hit back the browser will change the url in the address bar to the previous entry in the history **but will not reload the page since the url has not changed** (or at least this is my best guess of why). If I hit reload after hitting back I get the right page in the right way. So I was thinking about enhancing my .htaccess for this app with a rewrite rule that will say that this example url:

```
https://example.org/creditmanager/index.php?area=masterdata&sub=pf
```

will become:

```
https://example.org/creditmanager/masterdata/pf
```

This way the previous url may look as

```
https://example.org/creditmanager/masterdata/pg
```

and the browser will force the reload on back button.
I have found an example of a rule that can be close to mine in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435825/mod-rewrite-rule-for-a-url-with-multiple-get-variables)  but I need help to elaborate the concept to my goal (the first subdir is the area and the second is the sub in the url query).
Is anyone of you so kind to help me to elaborate the task?
So far I have only a rewrite condition in my site .conf file in apache that will redirect http:// requests to https:// and no .htaccess yet.

**EDIT**
Tried to add this directly to the conf file for apache:

```
<Directory /var/www/jdev/creditmanager/ >
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
</Directory>
```

*Note that the app root is in /var/www/jdev/ while the index.php is in the /creditmanager subdir*
Thanks!

Comment: When browser shows previous page `https://example.org/creditmanager/index.php?area=masterdata&sub=pf` can you check Apache access.log to see whether Apace also gets same URL request?

Comment: No. In access.log I see the get request for the content with the pushed url like: 188.218.142.195 - - [15/Aug/2015:17:12:15 +0200] "GET /images/sort_asc.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1739 "https://jenius.dyndns.org/creditmanager/index.php?area=masterdata&sub=pf" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4" but nothing on back

Comment: ok that means clicking on back is not sending any request to web server. In that case htaccess won't help.

Comment: Any idea on what I can do? Trigger an update on the back event maybe?